# Binding to a Collection of Strongly-Typed Objects in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a data class that contains a number of fields:

```
public class Person
{
    public int id { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

If I understand [Scott Hanselman's take on binding arrays of objects](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx), I should be able to create a form view that renders HTML that looks like this:

```
<input name="Person[0].id" value="26" type="hidden" />
<input name="Person[0].Name" value="Tom Smith" type="text" />
<input name="Person[0].Rate" value="40.0" type="text" />
<select name="Person[0].Type">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Full Time</option>
    <option value="2">Part Time</option>
</select>

<input name="Person[1].id" value="33" type="hidden" />
<input name="Person[1].Name" value="Fred Jones" type="text" />
<input name="Person[1].Rate" value="45.0" type="text" />
<select name="Person[1].Type">
    <option value="1">Full Time</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Part Time</option>
</select>
```

I should then be able to capture this data in my controller with an action method that looks like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult People(Person[] array)
{
    // Do stuff with array
}
```

But it doesn't work.  The array variable is always null.  I interpret this as the data binding is not working.  But why?

Comment: Might try a generic list instead of an array.

Comment: Tried List<Person> instead of Person[], still returns null.  The Hanselman pattern requires Person[].

Comment: Have you debugged and analysed your POST data to verify that the data is posted as per Scott's article?

Comment: not yet, but the data will successfully populate a FormsCollection variable.  I could parse that, but then I would be bypassing the binding system entirely.

Comment: What does the form markup look like?

Comment: After much research into this issue I have found that this now-old solution is still the best. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your fields should be named array[0].id, array[0].Type, ...

They should have the name of the array instance, not the name of the Type inside the array.

Alternatively you could change the signature of the actioncontroller to:
    Person[] Person

You get the point :-)

Comment: It took me about 10 seconds of looking at the link you posted.. it's one of those blind spot things that we all know and hate. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

```
<input name="Person[0].Rate" value="40.0" type="text" />
```

should be:

```
<input name="array[0].Rate" value="40.0" type="text" />
```