# Asp.Net MVC and models being sent back to client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a screen that is being drawn fine at the moment. But I need to add items to a table with the user clicks an 'Add' button. What I expect to happen is that the Post action adds a few properties in the model, to a list<>, and then sends the updated model back to the client. So, the user has entered a value in a control, clicks 'Add'... the full model gets sent back to the controller... the controller reads the properties and adds them to my List<> (which is part of the model). The model then gets sent back to the View, and a  is built, based on items in the list.

At the moment, I am trying this:

```
 public ActionResult AccountTransaction()
    {

        List<AccountDto> accounts = Services.AccountServices.GetAccounts(false);
        List<PayeeDto> payees = Services.PayeeServices.GetPayees();
        List<CostCenterDto> costCenters = Services.CostCenterServices.GetCostCenters();
        List<TransactionTypeDto> transactionTypes = Services.TransactionTypeServices.GetTransactionTypes();

        AccountTransactionView v = new AccountTransactionView
                                       {
                                           Accounts = (from a in accounts
                                                       where a.Deleted == false
                                                       select new SelectListItem
                                                                  {
                                                                      Text = a.Description,
                                                                      Value = a.AccountId.ToString(),
                                                                      Selected = false
                                                                  }

                                                      ),
                                           Payees = (from p in payees
                                                     where p.Deleted == false
                                                     select new SelectListItem
                                                                {
                                                                    Selected = false,
                                                                    Text = p.Name,
                                                                    Value = p.PayeeId.ToString()

                                                                }),
                                           TransactionTypes = (from tt in transactionTypes

                                                               select new TransactionTypeView
                                                                          {
                                                                              Deleted = false,
                                                                              Description = tt.Description,
                                                                              Value = tt.TransactionTypeId
                                                                          }).ToList(),

                                           CostCenters = (from cc in costCenters
                                                          where cc.Deleted == false
                                                          select new SelectListItem
                                                                     {
                                                                         Selected = false,
                                                                         Text = cc.Name,
                                                                         Value = cc.CostCenterId.ToString()
                                                                     }),
                                           Deleted = false,
                                           SelectedAccountId = 0,
                                           SelectedCategoryId = 0,
                                           SelectedSubCategoryId = 0,
                                           SelectedBudgetId = 0,
                                           TransactionDate = DateTime.Now
                                       };


        return View(v);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AccountTransaction(AccountTransactionView model)
    {
        model.TransactionSplitLines.Add(new TransactionSplitLine
                                            {Amount = "100", Category = "Test", SubCategory = "Test More"});
        return View("AccountTransaction", model);
    }
```

So, ' public ActionResult AccountTransaction()' is being called when the page is loaded... And the HttpPost method is being hit... but ... when I return View... the front end fails, as the model seems to be empty now. The view fails here:

```
            <td align="right">
            <% foreach (var tt in Model.TransactionTypes)
               {%>
            <%=tt.Description %>
            <%=Html.RadioButton("SelectedTransactionTypeId", tt.Value) %><br />
            <%
                }%>
        </td>
```

And this is being suddenly, Model.TransactionTypes is now Null... But, why, as I thought I was returning the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the entire `Model` property `null` or just the `TransactionTypes` property?  Remember that model binding works by building the objects from the data in a `post`.  For each of the `TransactionTypeView` objects to be present in the binded model in the `HttpPost` version of the `AccountTransaction` method, they need to be present in the `form` you are sending to the server.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966923/binding-to-a-collection-of-strongly-typed-objects-in-asp-net-mvc) discusses how to bind a collection of objects (and how to construct your markup to handle it).

Comment: Thanks. The model isn't null when I get it back... but the properties I created for the model (transactionTypes) in the first method, are all null. However, values post back (Date edit box.. etc) are there. It looks like I need to build those List values again?

Comment: That is honestly the easiest way to solve it without added a lot of potentially unneeded data on your page.

Comment: Thanks.. making progress, but ... I am passing a List<> in my model, to the view. That is then used to populate a <TABLE>. But... when I post back, the List<> is empty. Is there a way to return the list I passed in, without it being empty?

Comment: Yes, the contents of that list needs to be put into the page in the form that will be submitted.  The whole idea around model binding is that the MVC framework will transform these name / value pairs we get from the client into our strongly typed objects.  Here is a discussion about binding a list of objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966923/binding-to-a-collection-of-strongly-typed-objects-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I think he's trying to bind a list of data which actually is a property of his model, is this the same idea?