# shortterm storage of user selection from form to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to conceive of a way to store a list of selected items to the session, for later use.  I've googled and read examples for 2 hours now, and haven't found any examples that work.

The basic idea is this.  User sees a list of items to act upon.  User selects a number of them.  User chooses action to perform.  Controller takes list of selected items, and begins to act on them.

Am I thinking about this wrong?  It makes sense to me to use an Ajax action to store the 'select/unselect' action on the session object.  I really don't want an entire database object to handle this.  I just want a simple list of selected objects. In classic ASP, I'd  just have reacted to the selected items  in a form post, but that doesn't seem *right* in asp.net mvc....

How do I construct this behavior (with or without the Ajax, but preferable without the DB access)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get it, why not bind directly an array of `bool`s or something directly to your view's list of checkboxes? You can get them as parameters in your controller function and act upon them directly, with no middleman, they'd just be another `POST` value.

Or even better when you send in your list of items as part of your model, make them a structure that has a `bool selected=false` field that is bound to the checkbox next to the label, and you'll get the results back in your model directly.

Comment: I'm flying blind here...learning as I go.  That might be a great idea, but at the moment its not what I was looking for.  (not to say its wrong...)  Do you have an example I can look at to see how that works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966923/binding-to-a-collection-of-strongly-typed-objects-in-asp-net-mvc is the first hit in google, I'm sure you can find more. It's a pretty basic MVC concept, binding arrays to the view.

Comment: what search term? "mvc binding array to view" ?  I'm so new with this right now, that I don't know the right questions to send to goog.  I'm SURE its answered, but having a hard time asking the right questions. thanks :D

Comment: Sure that search term will work. The basics are as simple as naming your HTML inputs say `Persons[0].Name` where your model has an array of persons called `Persons` and each person has a property called `Name`. You do this in a `foreach` loop over `Model.Persons`.